# VS2015 Additional Include Directories not finding included header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, pdcurses

The question title says it all.
Here is the project settings for my addition include directories.
[image]
Here is my current program

```
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();                    /* Start curses mode */
    printw("Hello World !!!");    /* Print Hello World */
    refresh();                    /* Print it on to the real screen */
    getch();                      /* Wait for user input */
    endwin();                     /* End curses mode */

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors.

[image]

And the curses.h file is in the include folder
[image]

Anyone might have a clue as to where I went wrong?

Comment: It looks like you missed a slash between $(ProjectDir) and include

Comment: According to the documentation the slash is included in the macro

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `#include "curses.h"`, instead of `#include <curses.h>`